# separate the string by space

Tags: macros, strings

how to split parameter in an argument list of function by space

**\def\onto[1]{
....i don't know how to do
}**

or 
**\newcommand{\onto}[1]{
    #1 
}**
in #1 i get hello home as 1 string
in example i give

**\onto{hello, sonia}**
now i want to excess home and hello separate
so i can use home as separate string and hello as separate

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm sorry, but your question is not very clear. Can you please add an approximate representation of what you want that `\onto{hello,sonia}` should output?

Answer (score 3):

The `listofitems` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\splitarg[1]{%
  \setsepchar{ }%
  \readlist\myarg{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\splitarg{This is a very big test}
Here is argument 4: \myarg[4]

\def\tmp{This is a very big test}
\splitarg{\tmp}
Here is last argument: \myarg[-1]
\end{document}
```

[image]